# RDFLib OWL restriction with intersection in pretty-xml format

Tags: owl, rdflib

I'm trying to define the following class restriction in RDFLib:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="A">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="P"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom>
                    <owl:Class>
                        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                            <rdf:Description rdf:about="B"/>
                            <rdf:Description rdf:about="C"/>
                        </owl:intersectionOf>
                    </owl:Class>
                </owl:someValuesFrom>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>               
</owl:Class>
```

So I write:

```
c = BNode()
ontology.add((c, RDF.type, OWL.Class))
rdflib.collection.Collection(ontology, c, [B,C])
br1 = BNode()
ontology.add((br1, RDF.type, OWL.Class))
ontology.add((br1, OWL.intersectionOf, c))
br = BNode()
ontology.add((br, RDF.type, OWL.Restriction))
ontology.add((br, OWL.onProperty, P))
ontology.add((br, OWL.someValuesFrom, br1))
ontology.add((A, OWL.equivalentClass, br))
```

I have the following warning that I cannot get rid of:

> Assertions on rdflib.term.BNode('N89feccb53aad4bf4927a4a68e7c83af0') other than RDF.first and RDF.rest are ignored ... including RDF.List
> self.predicate(predicate, object, depth + 1)

**Update**
The problem arises only with the pretty-xml format.